# Issue in C language using 'fgets' after 'printf' as 'fgets' runs before 'printf'

Tags: c, printf, fgets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string? (in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

I am getting a problem using `printf` and `fgets` as in my code `printf` is written earlier then fget but it does not run, it runs after `fgets` runs.

```
enum { max_string = 127 };
static char string[max_string+1] = "";

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {    
      printf("Type a String: ");
      fgets(string, max_string, stdin);
      printf("The String is %s\n", string);
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

do a flush of the `stdout`

```
fflush(stdout);
```

before `fgets(...)`

```
printf("Type a String: ");  
fflush(stdout);
fgets(string, max_string, stdin);
```

Answer (score 1):

The point is not that `printf` runs after `fgets`, but instead that *its output* is displayed after it.

This happens because **standard output** (the file descriptor you're writing on with `printf`) is line-buffered, i.e. the standard library defers prints after a newline character (`\n`) has been received for printing.

From `man stdout`:

> The stream stdout is line-buffered when it points to a terminal. 
>   Partial lines will not appear until fflush(3) or exit(3) is called, or
>   a newline is printed.

To investigate different results, edit your example to use `fflush`, or print on standard error using `fprintf(stderr, ...` .

Answer (score 0):

put a `\n` in `printf` statement. This might be the problem as in `C` buffers are line terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Neel is right. If you want to just write something down without having to put that '\n' you can use the function write();

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { max_string = 127 };
static char string[max_string+1] = "";


my_putstr(char *str)
{
     write(1, str, strlen(str));
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {    
    my_putstr("Type a String: ");  
    fgets(string, max_string, stdin); 
    printf("The String is %s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```