# Can someone explain the behavior of fgets in my program?

Tags: c

When I use fgets in the following piece of code without the newline character in printf , the program does not wait for my input. It seems like either using a new line character in the printf statement before OR using the flushing the stdin fixes the problem. But can someone expain what's going on and why a \n or flsuhing fixes it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)

{

    char *userInput = malloc(sizeof(*userInput) * 2);

    printf("Enter a character:"); // This leads to an issue where fgets does not wait for an input

    /* 
    Using either of the below statements fixes it though 

    printf("Enter a character:\n");

    OR 

    fflush

    */


    fgets(userInput, 2, stdin);

    printf("The character you entered is: %c \n", userInput[0]);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: you can also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575102/issue-in-c-language-using-fgets-after-printf-as-fgets-runs-before-printf

Comment: regarding: `char *userInput = malloc(sizeof(*userInput) * 2);`  This allocates ( on a 32 bit architecture ) 8 bytes.  However, when reading from `stdin` (and similar sources )  a size around 1024 bytes would be much much better.  Suggest:  `char *userInput = malloc( 1024 );`  and always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Then the call to `fgets()` should be `if( fgets( userInput, sizeof( userInput ), stdin ) == NULL ) { // handle error and exit }

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the input, but if my program only needs to read 2 characters from stdin, are there still any advantages to allocating 1024 bytes?

Comment: If you want the user to enter 2 characters, then 1) ask for two characters, 2) check to assure that the user entered 2 characters, not just a single character and a newline or just a newline.  3) in a typical use of `fgets()` a newline will be included in the input AND a NUL byte will be appended to the user input.  So the desired input sizing would be 4 characters I.E.  `<char><char>\n\0`  There is no need to call `malloc()` for 4 characters, just use something like: `userInput[4];` and `fgets( userInput, sizeof( userInput ), stdin );`

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

For all C runtimes I'm aware of `stdout` is line buffered when connected to a terminal (and block buffered when connected to anything else), so output is only flushed to the screen when a newline is output, or `fflush` is used to explicitly flush the buffer. Without the newline (or an `fflush(stdout)` call), the `printf` output goes to the buffer, but never gets flushed to the screen.

Obviously, `fflush(stdout)` fixes this, as does actually outputting a newline. You could also globally disable buffering for `stdout` with [the `setvbuf` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf), though that risks slowing I/O.

Answer (score 0):

this is a proper way to have the user enter a single character then echo that char to the terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int userInput;

    printf("Enter a character:\n");

    if( (userInput = getchar() != EOF) )
    {
        printf("The character you entered is: %c \n", userInput);
    }
}
```

Your comments discuss the user entering two characters, BUT your code is only looking for 1 char (as is shown by your prompt to the user)

Comment: please look at your code once and edit `if( (userInput = getchar() != EOF) )` line as it will always prints either 1 or 0 instead of character entered